# Random gaps in product category grid (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I’ve a WooCommerce site and on mobile we’re getting strange empty spaces on product category pages. It seems to be ok on other archive pages though.

I’m thinking it could possibly be linked to the number of lines on a product title, but I don’t see why that should break it, or why it wouldn’t affect other pages.

I’ve go into Developer Mode (mobile) on browser and tried a few things – If I reduce the product title to two lines (same as other products on the same line) it fixes the gap. Alternatively, when I add clear:both to some of the product divs, it helps fix it.

Could it be that the template isn't specifying rows?

Example of the issue can be seen here on mobile: https://fusionworkwear.ie/product-category/softshelljackets/

I'm at the end of my tether on this one so any help would be **hugely** appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Set the **min-height** to **48px** for class name **product-title**
Here is the screenshot of your site when I set min-height ,
[image]

But, still the space will be added under title. Or else you can add this code in your css file.

```
.row.products div:nth-child(4n+1) {
   clear: left;
}
```

It works !

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. That seemed to fix the issue on that page, but the issue remains on others. Such as this; https://fusionworkwear.ie/product-category/quarter-zips/

Comment: can you tell me in brief ? because it displays perfect for me.

Comment: The code you suggested fixed the page I linked to in my original post. However, it does not fix other category pages, like this one - https://fusionworkwear.ie/product-category/quarter-zips/

I am still seeing the issue of the gap on the final product line.

Here's a screenshot: https://snipboard.io/WKt2bo.jpg